# Start on git: exclude ignored files is shows impossible

Tags: git

I'm new to this, and I've been almost a day wasting time in a .gitignore file. So I'm rather frustrated now. Anyways...

What I'm trying to achieve is very simple: ignore all things but a few. You'll get it quicky from this code:

```
*
!.gitignore
!README.md
!.vimrc
!.bashgit
!.bashrc*

!.config/alacritty/*
!.config/awesome/*
```

I just want git not to ignore some files in particular subdirectories. Promiss I've tried *everything* that is out there, nothing works.

Any help, please? _:-(

Comment: You need to explicitly un-ignore `.config` before you can un-ignore anything *within* `.config`, such as `.config/alacrity/*`.

Comment: if I add !.config/* same thing. @torek

Comment: Disregard my previous comments.

Comment: The `.config` directory is ignored so it doesn't matter you want to exclude files in there. Thus you have to exclude `.config` as well so you can specify ignore rules for that directory. And so on for any other subdirectories you want to exclude.

Comment: @JeffMercado I've tried everything. What you say would be !.config/ right? and this doesnt even show config on git status...

Comment: **Do not** use `!.config/*`, use either of `!.config` or `!.config/`. (This is complicated by Git's somewhat peculiar usage of trailing slash here: the trailing slash is deleted for purposes of deciding to ignore, but only when it's a *trailing* slash, so in `.config/*` it's not trailing and hence not deleted, and the whole thing goes wrong.)

Comment: @torek I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

So I checked out git docs. It's tough to read but there is this example:

```
  $ cat .gitignore
    # exclude everything except directory foo/bar
    /*
    !/foo
    /foo/*
    !/foo/bar
```

So I edited .gitignore like so:

```
/*
!.gitignore
!README.md
!.vimrc
!.bashgit
!.bashrc*

!/.config
/.config/*
!/.config/alacritty
!/.config/awesome
/.config/awesome/*
!/.config/awesome/autostart.sh
!/.config/awesome/rc.lua
```